# Redirect in angularjs using vm

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to redirect to a different route when i submit a form using angularjs and I am getting an error that says

> Cannot read property 'go' of undefined object

Below is my form code

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4 margin-top-30">
<form ng-controller="LogonController" data-ng-submit="vm.setDjName()" name="logonForm" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="dj-name" data-ng-model="vm.djName" placeholder="Your DJ Name" class="form-control">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-ng-click="vm.setDjName()" type="button">Login</button>
</form>
</div>
```

and here is my controller

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
.module('app.controllers')
.controller('LogonController', LogonController);

LogonController.$inject = [];

function LogonController ($state) {
var vm = this;
vm.setDjName = function () {
$state.go('/video');
}
}

})();
```

How would i restructure the code to make the redirect work?

Comment: $state is a service from ui-router but it doesn't appear as though you've injected ui-router in your module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to inject the `$state` service:

```
LogonController.$inject = ['$state'];

// or

angular
    .module('app.controllers')
    .controller('LogonController', ['$state', LogonController]);
```

Take a look at [angular dependency injection documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: You simply the best. Thank you.